# Textbox "Language " unwanted using Alfresco forms in Activiti Workflow

Tags: eclipse, workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I'm trying to develop my own workflow in Alfresco 4.2, using the examples of the predefined workflows that brings Alfresco and reusing its forms.

Using Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2, I create my own workflow  diagram from the Alfresco-Activiti design templates flows.

in all cases, since the start event, it's performed any of the predefines workflows using Form Key: wf:submitGroupReviewTask or wf:submitAdhocTask or other forms of Alfresco (see XML example) and once I copy the Eclipse bpmn file, rename it to bpmn20.xml and upload to Alfresco Enterprise from Admin console (http://xxx.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/activiti-admin#deployment) when I run the workflow that I created (I perform it on Alfresco Share) the Alfresco normal form appears, but with an additional textbox "Language:" which is also blocked and which you can not type (displayed on the screen just above the textbox "Comment: " and " Description: ").

**Does anyone know how to do for that field "Language:" does not appear ? .**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<definitions targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn20" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">


-<process isExecutable="true" name="UCAM basado en Ejemplo" id="UCAMbasadoenEjemplo">


-<extensionElements>


-<activiti:executionListener class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener" event="start">


-<activiti:field name="script">


-<activiti:string>

<![CDATA[execution.setVariable('wf_approveCount', 0); execution.setVariable('wf_actualPercent', 0); execution.setVariable('wf_requiredPercent', wf_requiredApprovePercent); ]]>

</activiti:string>

</activiti:field>

</activiti:executionListener>

</extensionElements>


-<startEvent name="Ucam Basado en Ejemplo -1" id="UcamBasadoenEjemplo-1" activiti:formKey="wf:submitGroupReviewTask">

<documentation>Documentacion START UCAM-1</documentation>

</startEvent>
```

Comment: you should post your share form config here as the form is configured there & not in your process definition

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) explains how Activiti workflow tasks map to types in the content model which can then be configured using the Alfresco Share form configuration XML.

After reading it you'll know how to make any field you want to show up or hide itself on your workflow forms in Alfresco.